# Octal to decimal and binary with wrong outputs

Tags: c, binary, decimal, octal

We were assigned a task to convert octal numbers to binary and decimal. Smaller numbers works just fine but it then gives a different output at a higher input. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  unsigned long n, g, ans = 1, r = 0, dec = 0, place = 1, bin = 0;
  printf("Conversion: Octal to decimal and binary.\n");
  printf("Enter number: ");
  scanf("%lu", &n);
  printf("%lu is ", n);

  for (g = n; g != 0; ans = ans * 8) {
    r = g % 10;
    dec = dec + r * ans;
    g = g / 10;
  }

  printf("%lu in Decimal Form. \n", dec);

  printf("%lu is ", n);
  for (; dec != 0; place = place * 10) {
    r = dec % 2;
    bin = bin + (r * place);
    dec = dec / 2;
  }
  printf("%lu in Binary Form.\n", bin);
}
```

We were only required to use limited data types and control structures. No arrays, strings, functions or such.

The input in our teacher's test case is `575360400` which must print an output of `101111101011110000100000000` in binary and `100000000` in decimal. But the output in binary is `14184298036271661312`. I used `unsigned long` already and it just won't work.

I don't know how this is possible with the given restrictions and your comments and answers will be really much of a help.

Comment: The code is reading the input as decimal. To read the input as octal, use `scanf("%lo", &n);`

Comment: Are you allowed to use `scanf`, or are you supposed to read one character at a time with `getchar()`?

Comment: @user3386109 does the keyword stays the same? I tried using ```%lo``` on both input and output and only the decimal output is right, not the binary.

Comment: we are only required to use ```scanf``` though

Answer (score 0):

> Smaller numbers works just fine but it then gives a different output at a higher input.

**Overflow**

Input `"575360400"` (base 8) converts to a 27-bit value.  For `place = place * 10 ... bin = bin + (r * place);` to work, `bin` needs to be a 90-bit `unsigned long`.  `unsigned long` is certainly 64-bit or less.

OP needs a new approach.

---

I'd start with reading the *octal* input with `scanf("%lo", &n);` and printing the *decimal* with `printf("%lu\n", n);`.

To print in binary, without arrays, functions, etc., consider a mask, first with the most significant bit, that is shifted right each iteration.

```
  bool significant_digit = false;

  // Form 0b1000...0000
  //                   0b1111... - 0b01111..
  unsigned long mask = ULONG_MAX - ULONG_MAX/2;

  while (mask) {
    bool bit = mask & n;
    if (bit || significant_digit || mask == 1) {
      significant_digit = true;
      printf("%d", bit);
    }
    mask >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n", bit);
}
```

[Better approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359) exist.  Yet with OP's artificial limitations: "No arrays, strings, functions or such.", I opted for something illustrative and simple.

---

**Or wait until 2023**

[C2x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features) expected to support `printf("%lb\n", n);`.  Just ask the professor for an extension .

Comment: ```bool``` does not work on my compiler oh my god, lemme try a different one

Comment: @PABLO1403 "bool does not work on my compiler" --> What C compiler and version are you using?  Be sure to add `#include <stdbool.h>`.  Alternate: `int bit = !!(mask & n);`.

Comment: I used ```#include<stdbool.h>``` and it seems to identify ```bool``` already. But I am confused about some variables such as ```ULONG_MAX``` and  ```bit```

Comment: @PABLO1403 The _constant_ `ULONG_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>` and is the maximum value for an object of type `unsigned long`.  `bit` is a _binary digit_: a unit of data storage that may have one of two values.